# Edited code.How to display gridview from dropdown list in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Hi I already posted this question but dint get answer please help me to display gridview  through dropdown list. Below is the code in vb.net

```
     Private Sub BindGridView()
    Dim filter As String = ""
    If ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue <> "" Then
        filter = filter & " AND OwnerDepartment ='" & ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue & "'"
    End If
    Dim table1 As DataTable = New DataTable("Details")
    table1.Columns.Add("ReferenceNo")
    table1.Columns.Add("Title")
    table1.Columns.Add("Counterparty")
    table1.Columns.Add("OwnerDepartment")
    table1.Columns.Add("Status")
    table1.Columns.Add("CreatedBy")
    table1.Columns.Add("CreatedOn")
    table1.Columns.Add("link")
    table1.Rows.Clear()
    Dim conSQL As New SqlConnection(conStrDRS)
    conSQL.Open()
    Dim cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Title, ReferenceNo,OwnerDepartment,CreatedBy,CreatedOn,Status,Counterparty " & _
                                     " FROM [dbo].[Registration]" & filter)

    cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
    Dim adptSQL As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
    Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
    adptSQL.Fill(myDataSet)
    conSQL.Close()
    gvDetails.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0) 'dvAlert
    gvDetails.DataBind()
End Sub         

 Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    BindGridView()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Why you are applying the filter on `OwnerDepartment` twice? Also, you should use parametrized query to avoid SQL injection attack.

Comment: hello avi what is the issue ? any error ? exception please come with specific thing in question

Comment: when I click search no data available.

Comment: Hi Rahul I want to serch gridview through ownerdepartment also it is dropdown list

Comment: Can I have update on this

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating `filter` and end of `sql query` which is not needed because `filter` has same value which you are already adding at end of query.

Also don't concatenate values use `Parameterized SQL`. Add paramter to your sql query like this.

```
Dim cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Title, ReferenceNo,OwnerDepartment,CreatedBy,CreatedOn,Status,Counterparty " &
                                 " FROM [dbo].[Registration] Where OwnerDepartment=@OwnerDepartment");
cmdSQL.Paramters.AddWithValue("@OwnerDepartment",ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue);
```

**EDIT**

```
Private Sub BindGridView(bool showAll)
Dim filter As String = ""
If ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue <> "" Then
    filter = filter & " AND OwnerDepartment ='" & ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue & "'"
End If
Dim table1 As DataTable = New DataTable("Details")
table1.Columns.Add("ReferenceNo")
table1.Columns.Add("Title")
table1.Columns.Add("Counterparty")
table1.Columns.Add("OwnerDepartment")
table1.Columns.Add("Status")
table1.Columns.Add("CreatedBy")
table1.Columns.Add("CreatedOn")
table1.Columns.Add("link")
table1.Rows.Clear()
Dim conSQL As New SqlConnection(conStrDRS)
conSQL.Open()
Dim cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Title, ReferenceNo,OwnerDepartment,CreatedBy,CreatedOn,Status,Counterparty FROM [dbo].[Registration] ";

if showAll==false then
cmdSQL += "Where OwnerDepartment=@OwnerDepartment");
cmdSQL.Paramters.AddWithValue("@OwnerDepartment",ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue);
End If

cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
Dim adptSQL As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
adptSQL.Fill(myDataSet)
conSQL.Close()
gvDetails.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0) 'dvAlert
gvDetails.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
BindGridView(true)
End Sub
```

Now when you call this function from `dropdown search` pass false from that function to `BindGridView(false)`

Comment: Hi Mairaj it works but my question is I want to display when click search button please help me to that. Thanks for your answer

Comment: IT should work can u check when you click on button are you getting value in `ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: No it shows only from dropdown list not when click search

Comment: My aim is want to display data when I click search button. if I search in dropdown list it shows only selected value data in gridview but when I click search I should display all the data I hope you understand now

Comment: Ok when search button is clicked than dont add where clause in `sql query `and when you search through dropdown than add where clause in `sql query`.

Comment: Sorry i don't know syntax just wanted to give you the idea and forgot to mention this that i don't know exact syntax.